# Regex expression - select all NOT having a specific attribute and NO new lines

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

If would like to select any lines that has an XML statement but within there need to be a missing attribute. So I'm able to find bad data very easily.

So this solution here works, but in my example I do not have any new lines. It's without any whitespaces.

**Regex:**

```
/^<SomeState((?!SearchedAttribute).)*$/gm
```

works good on:

[image]

but when the whitespaces are deleted it does not because of the `^` [image]

and it does not find them anymore.

How can I do this with everything on the same line?

Idea #1:

```
/<SomeState((?!SearchedAttribute).)*/gm
```

is already better but I don't want to have the conditions selected:

[image]

Teststring:

```
<SomeState><SearchedAttribute Key=Value/></SomeState>
<SomeState><SearchedAttribute Key=Value/></SomeState>
<SomeState Attr1><BadAttribute Key=Value/></SomeState>
<SomeState><SearchedAttribute Key=Value/></SomeState>
<SomeState><BadAttribute Key=Value/></SomeState>
```

Comment: Which flavour of regex?

Comment: You should probably be using an XML parser, given that you have nested content here.

Comment: XML parser might be better but I would like to have it solved in regex. Thanks.

Comment: It would be really great if you would provide your data as text and not as images! Results can also be shown via regex101.com

Comment: Depending on your needs, if you just need a visual confirmation, whenever the match is long (> 12 char), you found a culprit...

Comment: Find the test string above @csabinho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution via deleting whitespaces. So if you have **notepad++** and the **XML Tools** addon. You will have the option Linarize XML:
[image]

Now copy the single-line XML string and run it through this regex:

```
/<SomeState((?!SearchedAttribute).)*SomeState/gm
```

This works as expected and just selects the bad extries.